# Popup and Redux Reducers

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'd like to know how to handle specific use case with redux reducer. To give an example, say I have a form with a DataGrid/Table. On Edit button click from a row, I want to open the popup with seleted row-data. After editing the data, On Popup-Submit button click, I want to update the Table/DataGrid (i.e. DataGrid will now should have the edited values).

I've written two separate Components 
1. MainPage.js and its corresponding reducer MainPageReducer (Employee List)
2. PopupPage.js and its corresponding reducer PopupPageReducer (Selected Employee)

How these two reducers share the state?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Reducers don't share state. You'll need to map specific state to components in order to 'share' state. That way in any dispatching actions in a component will propagate this 'shared' state to any reducers that are listening.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to read this first
http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

The main concept is that through the **connect** function, you would simply map needed properties of your state to the properties of your component i.e MapStateToProps. So in your case, imagine that your state, for contrived purposes, is structed like so:

```
{employees: {employees: {1: {id: 1, name: 'Foo'}}, editedEmployeeId: 1}
```

- You could map the array of employees to an employees property for your EmployeeList component whilst also mapping a dispatch function, named editEmployee(id) to a click function on each row in the table.
- You could map [the employee with the associated editedEmployeeId] to the individual employee in your employees array for your popup component

It may be efficient to just use one reducer instead of two. 
Specifically, if you're making  **an update to an individual employee** then you would call an EDIT_EMPLOYEE action and then a SAVE_EMPLOYEE action on save. After the SAVE_EMPLOYEE action, then, I assume, you'd call a post method, and then react-redux would re-render your entire list.

It could look like this:

```
function employees(state = {editedEmployeeId: undefined, employees = []}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case EDIT_EMPLOYEE:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {editedEmployee: action.employee_id})
        case SAVE_EMPLOYEE:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {employees: action.employees});
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

There are great holes in my answer because the question you're asking might be too broad; I'm presuming you don't fully understand how the connect, subscribe, and dispatch functions work.

Like one of the comments said, **reducers don't share state. They simply take the previous version of your state and return another version of it.**
Anyways, hope this helps. Read the redux docs!

Comment: Very good answer. However, directly editing the original employee without creating a copy is dangerous because the user can't go back and cancel edition. On top of that, using something like `redux-form` which the op probably will end finding out about will be harder. I normally create a copy of the item being edited so I can discard it or pass it as a form model.

Comment: oh, i see. That makes sense. Can you give me an example of how you would create an example of how you would normally create a copy and store it in state? I'm not fully grasping what you're asking?